# Regression with ranked and truncated dependent variable

Tags: ordinal-data, ranks, truncated-distributions

I'm struggling to find a model that will best fit this data.

The dependent variable is the ranking of a observation based on how many votes it received based of a list of choices (number of votes is unknown, only ranking). 
Only ranking of Top 100 are reported, the rest forming ranking =>101. 
I have about 10 years of theses rankings with abut 1000 data points in each year.

Ordered probit/logit would be useful as the rankings are ordinal values however i have heard that ordered probit can have computation issues with over 10 categories. I am also concerned that a data set with only 1 data point per year in each category up to 100 and then thousands in the =>101 category may cause results to be nearly meaningless. I have also thought about grouping the ranks into 1-10, 11-20, to reduce the number of categories.

The other model i have thought about is truncated model and assume the ranks are evenly spaced in terms of votes and treat them like ratio values.

Explanatory variables will a mix of dummy and ratio values.

Essentially what i am looking for is a combination of the truncated and ordered probit/logit models however im not sure if such a model exists and has software libraries for it or is even appropriate. Have i missed something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question--models exist for exactly this situation, which is called a "top-$t$" ranking (we only observe the top $t$ items of the potentially infinite ranking). Plackett-Luce tends to work well in practice and is easy to estimate. The Mallows model is another option. I would start by reading up on Plackett-Luce and see if it'll work for you.